# Sequence generation type issue sql jpa

Tags: java, sql, jpa, sequence

I am using an Id auto GeneratedType sequence

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

I am having the below values in the table for the Id column

```
180
181
182
200
230
```

But my sequence seems to be incrementing from `180,181 and 183` sequence eventhough I already have `200 and 230` in the table

And gradually the sequence reaches 200 and I am getting a unique key exception.

Is there any way I can manage the GenerationType so that it will increment based on the largest value available in the column.

```
How can I make the next increment to be 231 instead of 184?.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value of the sequence by using `initialValue` property.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TABLE1_SEQ", sequenceName = "TABLE1_SEQ", initialValue = 231)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "TABLE1_SEQ")
```

If the values are added to your table from outside the jpa application ideally use the same sequence (or whatever generation strategy you use) from the database so that the sequence stays up to date.

You can also use the Table Generator or identity generation if it suits you better.

You can also use an SQL script to update the sequence directly in the database. 
However, if you concurrently keep updating the same table outside of JPA, there is no direct way to tell JPA to always use the maximum id.

Comment: what is the purpose of table generator or identity generator

Comment: They are other types of strategies available (like sequences). You can choose one based on your Database System. The reason I mentioned them is that since the ids 200 and 230 exist, they must have been created outside your JPA application without using the sequence i.e. some other way of ID generation so it would be best to sync up your JPA application with the same ID generation strategy used outside of JPA or you'll end up in situations such as what  you are experiencing now. In short change your JPA application code or your non-JPA application code to match one another.